# Invert width/height direction

Tags: css

There is somehow "legal" to reverse the direction in which an object grow (width / height)? Generally increase value of the width of the object it grows from left to right. My idea is to increase in the opposite direction.

Basically, I need to create a dropdown menu when you click an option, however, defined menus on most right of the page will need to grow in the opposite direction, so I do not have to fix position via javascript.

**I know some possibilities:**

- Do it via javascript, as I said. However, I would not want to do it this way.
- Using relative positioning. But it would be a possibility? How?
- Perhaps use `float: right`?

I got up the concept, but not sure how to actually implement the most *cost-effective-like*. Well, is open the possibility to send a suggestion. The better the effect and reduced maintenance, better.

Comment: Use a negative value.. ie, `-100px`...?

Comment: Negative values to width, you mean? It seems that it doesn't works. Almost here. :( But thanks.

Comment: Never tried myself, but how about `direction: rtl`?

Comment: @JoshC we cannot use negative widths and heights :) -David I didn't read your question, but from the title, it seems that what you are trying to achieve is not possible

Comment: Not sure I understand clearly what you mean (can you post a jsfiddle ?). There may be one way to do it : as you suggested, you can do something like that :`<div style="float: left"><div style="float: right"></div></div>`

Comment: @Mr.Alien Yea - I know. That's incorrect syntax. I should have worded it to state that you could use things such as negative margins, or even negative positioning. Didn't mean to imply that you could use negative widths/heights.

Comment: @JoshC yea perfect :)

Comment: I'm not entirely certain what the intent is either, but I think `float: right;` should be all you need. To expand on the comment by @Harry , you can also use `direction` if you want to avoid floating elements (could help with positioning in some cases) http://jsfiddle.net/HDG7R/

Comment: The question is far too abstract and vague. You should describe some actual rendering you want, with markup and visual illustration, and with a description of dynamic behavior if needed (e.g., opening and closing a dropdown, and the associated functionality).

Comment: And what about padding??

Answer (score 1):

Well I will try something ...

**CSS:**

```
#test {
    background:#000;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:Arial;
    border-radius:10px;
    color:#fff;
    float:left; /* You can make it true, if you dont this, the element will grow up in all directions */
    padding:4px 4px 50px 40px; /* With 50px and 40px, you can grow up this element in a "inverted way" */
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="test">Test</div>
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ezzYk/

Comment: Float is for left, right and everywhere. How about up and down?